# Error on load slds.css in a public visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, error, slds

I have two sandboxes, in one of them I'm developing this visualforce page that uses slds, when I deployed the features to the other sandbox the slds.css doesn't load. In the first sandbox works just fine, but in the second i'm getting this weird error.

- The visualforce already have the tag <apex:slds> inside the <head> tag
- On the body already have a div with class slds-scope
- the tag <apex:page> have this parameters

```
    standardStylesheets="false" 
    sidebar="false" 
    applyHtmlTag="false"
    applyBodyTag="false" 
    docType="html-5.0"
```

In the console log on the browser have this error
[image]

[image]

My guess is that I forgot to deploy some configuration to enable this option in this public visualforce page, what i'm missing?